# Executing dynamic SQL with return value as a column value for each rows

Tags: sql-server

I have a rather simple query that I started to modify in order to remove temp table as we have concurrency issues over many different systems and clients.

Right now the simple solution was to break up the query in multiple separate queries to replicate what SQL was doing before.

I am trying to figure out a way to return the result of a dynamic SQL query as a column value. The new query is quite simple, it look in the system objects for all table with specific format and output. What i am missing is that for each record i need to output the result of a dynamic query on each of those table.

The query :

```
SELECT [name] as 'TableName' 
FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE xtype = 'U' 
AND (CHARINDEX('_PCT', [name]) <> 0 
OR CHARINDEX('_WHT', [name]) <> 0)
```

All these table have a common column called `Result` which is a float. What i am trying to do is return the count of this column under some `WHERE` clause that is generic and will work will all tables as well.

A desired query (i know it's not valid) would be :

```
SELECT [name] as 'TableName',
sp_executesql 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + [name] + ' WHERE Result > 0 OR (Result < 139 AND CurrentIndex < 15)' as 'ResultValue'
FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE xtype = 'U' 
AND (CHARINDEX('_PCT', [name]) <> 0 
OR CHARINDEX('_WHT', [name]) <> 0)
```

Before it used to be easy. We had a temp table with 2 columns and were filling the table name first. Then we iterate on the temp table and execute the dynamic sql and return the value in an `OUTPUT` variable and simply update the record of the temp table and finally return the table.

I have tried a scalar function but it doesn't support dynamic SQL so it doesn't work. I would rather not create the 13,000~ different queries for the 13,000~ tables.

I have tried using a reference table and use trigger to update the status but it slow the system way to much. The average tables insert and delete 28 millions records. The original temp table query only took 5-6 minutes to execute due to very good indexing and now we are reaching 25-30 minutes.

Is there any other solution available than Querying the table list then the Client query each table one by one to know it status ?

We are using SQL Server 2017 if some new features are available now

Comment: Any solution where you end up with 13000 tables is *more* than suspect. For starters, *that many objects* being accessed concurrently makes it more than likely that your transaction log ends up as a bottleneck, instead of the data. Not  that I'm suggesting you should have 13000 databases instead, but there might be some acceptable middle ground. For concurrency issues, look into things like snapshot isolation, in-memory tables and partitioning. Explicitly creating hordes of smaller objects leads to enormous maintenance headaches for queries, as you've discovered.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Performance wise i think i am fine that server has 96 cores 192 threads and ~2+ terabyte ram. For transaction they are not that big. Transaction over the days don't total very large datawise. They are all small tables. I have about 1.5-2 tb of data per day of changes. It's a replication of the main server which is much more powerful but still i think speed is fine. Haven't had issues other than that single query using temp tables since we switched to those new servers (2-3 months ago).

Comment: None of what I said is contingent in any way on your hardware resources, and my suggestion is not to simply upgrade your hardware. Indeed, unless you're really trying your best I'd expect most of those 192 threads to be idle most of the time, because the bottleneck should be I/O. I would worry far more about the fact that you have a design with 13000 tables. If these are, say 1000 instances of the same 13 tables, one for each customer, it would still make more sense to have 1000 databases, simply because that gives you 1000 transaction logs as opposed to 1.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Ah i get what you mean. No they are not same instances. They all differs in some ways,. They are in fact data points with different properties for machine learning before the crunching. These data get renewed over and over and crunch and crunch. The goal is to know what table which represent a real world object has been crunched or not so we can attribute the work to someone to work on it.

Comment: T-SQL is just not very good at concurrency, except for when it can flex its muscles over a partitioned table or a columnstore index. The language itself is purely sequential. Querying over 13000 tables is inherently inefficient no matter how you slice it, because any approach in T-SQL is going to involve sequentially iterating through all the tables -- only individual queries can profit from parallelism. If you cannot or do not want to reduce the number of tables, consider writing dedicated client code for this that can open parallel connections.

Comment: There is no way you can execute a dynamic query and get a result back in a SELECT statement. This type of work in sql requires iteration. Your original approach of iterating through a temp table and executing the dynamic sql with a return value in a  variable is how it is mostly done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script for your purpose (tested in SQL Server 2016).

**Updated:** It should work now as the results are a single set now.

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable
@precommand = 'CREATE TABLE ##Statistics 
    (TableName varchar(128) NOT NULL, 
    NumOfRows int)',
@command1 ='INSERT INTO ##Statistics (TableName, NumOfRows)
    SELECT ''?'' Table_Name, COUNT(*) Row_Count FROM ? WHERE Result > 0 OR (Result < 139 AND CurrentIndex < 15)',
@postcommand = 'SELECT TableName, NumOfRows FROM ##Statistics;
    DROP TABLE ##Statistics'
,@whereand = ' And Object_id In (Select Object_id From sys.objects
    Where name like ''%_PCT%'' OR name like ''%_WHT%'')'
```

For more details on **sp_msforeachtable** Please visit [this](https://www.sqlshack.com/an-introduction-to-sp_msforeachtable-run-commands-iteratively-through-all-tables-in-a-database/) link

Comment: You can put those conditions in an `IF` in the query itself: `IF ('?' LIKE '%_PCT%' OR '?' LIKE '%_WHT%') SELECT...` so no result set is produced for tables we don't care about. However, note that `sp_msforeachtable` is a simple linear cursor loop under the covers, so it will perform quite poorly when it has to run over 13000 tables, and rendering 13000 result sets isn't going to be a picnic either.

Comment: @JeroenMostert bit updated but still one checking undone that is xtype = 'U'.

Comment: We don't need it, because `xtype = 'U'` checks that the object type is a table -- that's covered by `sp_msforeachtable` itself.

Comment: That's great and that case the script should serve OP's purpose, right?

Comment: I don't think so, because I'm pretty sure the OP doesn't want 13000 separate result sets, and if they do they probably want them faster than what `sp_msforeachtable` can achieve -- but that's for the OP to decide.

Comment: Edited and all purpose should serve now.

Comment: @mkRabbani I have tried your version just before your current update and i don't know why but it's faster than the original temp table version. I get sub 5 minutes. Yes it's split in many result set but i don't get why it's so much faster than a temp table. It make no sense. Checking you new version just after i am done with learning about that storeproc

Comment: @Franck: be aware that `sp_msforeachtable`, while a staple of many ad-hoc scripts, is not officially documented or supported. What it does is fairly easy to do on your own with a hand-written cursor loop over `select [name] from sys.tables` -- I typically prefer this because the `?` approach of `sp_msforeachtable` very easily breaks on tables with unconventional names, whereas using `QUOTENAME` will not (plus, it's easier to see what's happening with explicit code).

Comment: @mkRabbani The new version you wrote use temp table which cause me the problem to start with. I will go with the previous version with the multiple table output as long as it's a single query i can live with having a dataset instead of a datatable. This is so trivial and solve so much issues that it's not a problem.

Comment: That's great @Franck. In addition, its a great learning for me as well :)